# how can I get a variable from a function jquery

Tags: jquery, closures

sorry for my eng//)
how can i get count_val and use outside the function ?

```
function change_count(){
        var count_val = 0;
        $('input[name="count"]').keyup(function(){
            count_val = parseFloat($(this).val())||0;
            //console.log(count_val);
            //alert(count_val);
        });
        //alert(count_val);
        //console.log(count_val);

    }
    change_count();
    alert(count_val);
```

Comment: Your logic is strange, but you can just return the value you want

Answer (score 2):

Your logic here is very flawed as the `count_val` value won't be changed until the `keyup` function has fired, but that will never happen until after the `alert` has been run, so the value will always show `0`. Instead keep your logic within the `keyup` handler.